# How to stop MongoDb from creating index for the database out of some of the keys in the schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique:true},
    fullname: {type: String, unique:false,default:''},
    email: {type: String, unique:true},
    password: {type: String, unique:false, default: ''},
    userImage: {type: String, default:'default.png'},
    facebook: {type: String, default: ''},
    fbTokens: Array,
    google: {type: String, default:''}
}, {timestamps: true});
```

This is my User schema. If i delete the indexes that are created on email,password,username and fullname and restart my express app using mongoose, it recreates these db indices. How to prevent this from happening ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the indexes on those fields then simply remove the `unique:true/false` parts from your schema definition. Mind you, if you need to enforce true uniqueness across your collection then this will always need to be done through unique indexes on the db (MongoDB) level.

The [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html) states:

> unique: {Boolean} - Tells Mongoose to ensure a unique index is created
>   for this path.